# Clarification needed on tensforflow code in gen_array_ops.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py

Line 17
from tensorflow.python.framework import op_def_library as **_op_def_library**

Line 33 
result = **_op_def_lib**.apply_op("BatchMatrixBandPart", input=input, num_lower=num_lower, num_upper=num_upper, name=name)

how it calls _op_def_lib in line 33 while its defined as _op_def_library in line 17 ?

Comment: Heh... I hope you get your answer. A quick search in git history tells me that this file was never added or deleted, so it must have been generated by the build process. And there are dozens of references to it through the code, so it must be working somehow.

Comment: Thanks Mad! I understand the file is machine generated, but my question is that the syntax is wrong, so I was just curious to know the cause of same. Do you agree that the syntax is wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I do. There must be some magic going on, since too many ops would be broken if this was an actual bug.

Comment: Thanks @MadWombat !